# Older Delta 1400 1500 series too far recessed after changing shower walls

Tags: shower, delta

So, I screwed up. Big Time. I demoed my bathroom and paid someone to rebuild it. I bought new shower to go in. The old one was direct to stud. The new one was not, the best way I can describe it is the inside wall of the shower wall is about 1-2 in away from the stud. the end result is when it was all done, I mean the entire bathroom is done, I go to put on the vanity plate and shower handle and it doesn't fit right. There is a gap because the entire shower mechanism is recessed in the wall too far for the new shower. I can not find anything to extend it. There are extenders, but they are all for other brands or other models of Delta. Its copper so there is no "flex" to it. I can't just unscrew and pull the mechanism forward, at least not enough. Any ideas?[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. While your description is reasonably clear about what the problem is, some pictures from inside the shower stall, and, even better from behind the wall (you do have an access hatch of some sort, don't you) will help people help you figure out a good course of action.

Comment: So they 5-spotted large wall tile but never moved the rough-in valve forward to accommodate the distance?

Comment: Not sure what 5-spotted means lol.... but essentially, yes, I demo'd the room. Explained what was there etc.. I then purchased materials, including a new shower set from Lowes. The old set was direct to stud. the new set was not. They were "thick". Only after it all was done did we realize that the shower valve housing was pretty far inside the wall, keeping the cartridge from being fully present inside the shower. I am certain a professional could just cut the pipes and move the valve assembly outward and then reconnect the pipes with some fancy copper kung-fu... but I am not that guy.

Comment: I also cannot afford the several hundred dollars that I am sure it would cost. The bathroom remodel broke me and then I had a personal issue come up last week, so I am looking for a DIY solution. If it really works well I will never change it. If it halfway works I will put back money to pay for the real fix later.

Comment: My current idea is a a well lubed thick 2 in. rubber seal to put around the handle to fill the gap and make sure indirect spray doesnt make it through there.

Comment: 5-spotting is a shortcut used by tile installers to easily get tiles to lay flush. I've seen this method cause as much as a 1 inch gap between the tile and substrate and it is utterly prone to issues in as little as one year. It is common with large format tiles because doing it right requires a perfectly flat substrate and most homes do not have flat substrates. If you're installer did this then I'd want my money back. https://www.ceramictilefoundation.org/blog/eliminate-spot-bonding-ceramic-tile-installation

Comment: Please consider providing a zoomed out picture. Without knowing what your wall material is then it's hard to make any relevant recommendations. If the escutcheon plate is your only form of access then it is very unlikely to be successful via DIY. If there is an access panel behind your shower wall then the odds of DIY become much higher.

Comment: The shower is a Khoeler Ensemble Curve. I took some more pictures last night. I will add them.Last night I added a foam pad from one of the optional cover plate pieces and an undersized greased o-ring to try to block the gap. It worked somewhat but i would really like a larger gasket or o-ring. or possibly add a layer of grease over top of it.

Comment: It's hard to tell from the 3rd pic down, but there _seems_ to be enough clearance to operate the handle. Instead, it looks like there's some sort of seal _missing_ between the handle and the escutcheon plate, and that's what's causing the large gap where water could run down. Maybe include a side-on picture, and a picture of the install instructions.

Comment: This does seem like something your remodeler should've done. That said, the only good fix that I can suggest is to open the wall from the other side and move the valve assembly.

Comment: FreeMan, I am 100% certain that the parts are all there. It should have been moved forward and it wasn't. The handle works fine. The gap is the only concearn. The gap would not be there if the mechanism was moved out and the cap which is slightly flared and over larger in diameter than the handle, were to take up the space of the gap.

Comment: isherwood, unfortantely the front bath is a full bath and both of the shower/bath units are head to head. There is no way to access from the other side. If I want it fixed, I either need a pro who can do everything blind from the access hole for the handle, or I need my brand new dry wall cut, the shower wall removed, the work done and then the wall reinstalled and the drywall fixed. Terribly upsetting turn of events.

Comment: A Delta shower body of this type has mounting holes for screws on the upper left and of the lower right of the center of the body. Those screws should still be visible when you remove the finish plate. Loosening or even removing those screws should allow you to pull the body outward as long as the copper tubing isn't strapped too close to the body. Whether the distance gained is enough is the only question. You can always replace  those screws with longer ones if needed. Good Luck.